# PowerShell Job.Progress contains multiple objects

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am currently developing a backup manager for Hyper-V using PowerShell.

I ran into problems when starting an export job like this:

```
$job = (export-vm -name "Windows 10" -path F:\VM_Backup\ -asjob)
```

Now when querying the progress of the job I realized that two objects are inside my `Progress` property:

```
> $job.progress

ActivityId        : 0
ParentActivityId  : -1
Activity          : Export wird ausgeführt
StatusDescription : Gelöscht
CurrentOperation  :
PercentComplete   : 1
SecondsRemaining  : -1
RecordType        : Processing

ActivityId        : 0
ParentActivityId  : -1
Activity          : Export wird ausgeführt
StatusDescription : Gelöscht
CurrentOperation  :
PercentComplete   : 37
SecondsRemaining  : -1
RecordType        : Processing
```

While the second progress update makes real progress (increasing percentage), the first one always stays like above.

I have never seen this behavior before and that really doesn't make any sense to me. How do I (programmatically) select the "right" job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, the [`.Progress` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job.progress) *collects all progress messages* written by the job - it doesn't just reflect the *latest* status.

The *most recently written* message is the last one added to the `.Progress` collection, so you can use index `[-1]` to retrieve it.

```
$job.Progress[-1]
```

Note: For `Start-Job`-created jobs, you must access the `.Progress` property on the (one and only) *child* job instead: `$job.ChildJobs[0].Progress[-1]` - see [`about_Job_Details`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_job_details).